Correct way to say: Registration is necessary or Registration is needed
How would you say:
Registration is necessary  or registration is needed?

With need:  Informal would be  "you need to register" and formal "one needs to register".   **need to ___" is synonymous with "must ___".

Both are fine, but registration is required is much more common.
Ngram
